# Content Delivery API- Restricted Access & Filters

Tags: episerver, optimizely

I have setup content delivery api including content search api to query the content to be used in another front end application.

Packages that are include within the solution are:
[image]

Here's the config settings that i have included
[image]

With the initial setup, the content delivery api works. However, there are a few issues that  I am facing & a few clarifications that are required:

1- SetMinimumRoles()- This when empty, allows anonymous access to content api. However,  to restrict access, I believe, **this setting is not required & as given in the optimizely documentation below, a token access is required & using the generated token ,i need to use the apis. Is this the correct understanding or is there a different way to handle the restricted access?**
https://world.optimizely.com/documentation/class-libraries/rest-apis/content-delivery-api/content-delivery-api/

2- Filters:

When trying to use filters, this is what i get.I have tried other filters that are provided in
https://docs.developers.optimizely.com/content-management-system/v1.5.0-content-delivery-api/docs/content-search-api
but nothing works.
Is there a specific format that it is expecting when working with filters?

The Episerver version that I am working on is CMS 11.

[image]